# Substituindo valores NA de uma coluna pelo valor da linha de cima da mesma coluna de um dataframe

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho o data frame abaixo, e quero criar um script para substituir os `NA` pelo valor da linha de cima da mesma coluna.

```
DADOS <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4), 
  b = c(5, 6, 7, NA, NA)
)
```

Abaixo o resultado como gostaria:

```
DADOSRESULTADO <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4), 
  b = c(5, 6, 7, 7, 7)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

A função `na.locf` do pacote `zoo` faz exatamente o que é pedido:

```r
library(zoo)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric

na.locf(DADOS)
#>   a b
#> 1 1 5
#> 2 2 6
#> 3 2 7
#> 4 3 7
#> 5 4 7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa seria utilizar **fill** do pacote **tidyr**:

```
library(tidyr)

DADOS <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4), 
  b = c(5, 6, 7, NA, NA)
)

DADOS %>% fill(a,b)
```

Saída:

```
  a b
1 1 5
2 2 6
3 2 7
4 3 7
5 4 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Mais uma opção, a função `data.table::nafill`. A variação `setnafill` pode ser usada para modificar por referência:

```
library(data.table)

setnafill(DADOS, "locf")

DADOS
#>   a b
#> 1 1 5
#> 2 2 6
#> 3 2 7
#> 4 3 7
#> 5 4 7
```

Pode usar também "const" para preencher com um valor fixo e "nocb" para usar o valor seguinte. A opção `cols` permite definir colunas por nome ou número (o padrão é aplicar à todas).